# Windows 10 can't show my wifi (netgear Nighthawk AX8)

Tags: windows, windows-10, wifi

I bought the new Netgear Wifi 6 AX8 and installed over AT&T connection, turning AT&T router into a bridge mode. Everything worked fine and all my devices are now connected to my new router (around 10 devices / computers). I changed the network name to something else. The netgear shows itself to all my devices when I search for Wifi network but windows 10. I have an Acer laptop not too old (2 years ago). I already updated the driver, reinstalled, reset it, enable/disabled, reboot, you name it, but my network is not shown on the network list. I can see many available networks but mine. Do you know what's going on? My new router seems to be configured properly, with SSID enabled and two networks 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz running fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after struggle with that for hours I found out the solution, which is pretty simple. DON'T TRUST MICROSOFT. So, when Microsoft tell you they updated your driver when you are at the driver configuration, don't believe it. Go to your driver source and download it from there. I went to intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html and downloaded the Intel Driver & Support Assistant. From there I verified that the wifi driver should be updated. I did that using Intel program and now I can see my Netgear wifi. Simple but I was misguided by this sh**t Windows.